# Automate Tab Name to match cell value

Tags: excel, vba

So I have this working code to have my tab name = C4 (which also contains a simple formula =IF(Schedule!C5="","#1",Schedule!C5).  However, if this cell is changed or updated the tab name doesn't change automatically.  Basically user has to go in cell C4 and double click just to hit enter then the tab name updates.  Any help to get this to be automatic?  Thanks in advance!

Here is my current code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C4")) Is Nothing Then
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Daily - " & ActiveSheet.Range("C4")
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Formula updates don't trigger as Worksheet_Change event. You will have to use the worksheet-change event of sheet Schedule and check for Range C5 - as this change also triggers the update of the formula. But I am not sure what will happen first: update of formula or worksheet_change -event ...

Comment: Ok thank you.  I figured I was barking up the wrong tree.  I will work on revising some code and see if I can get it to trigger.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to change on the fly with the following code thanks for the advice!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
On Error Resume Next
Sheet1.Name = "Daily - " & Range("C4").Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the change is happening in C5, then `Intersect(Target, Range("C4"))` will return `Nothing` because the `Target` is C5 even though a change did happen in C4 due to formula re-calculation.

To properly check for changes in C4, we need to look at its [Precedents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.precedents), because a change to one of those means that there has been a change in C4. With your formula, C5 is a Precedent of C4.

So we need to check if `Target` is either C4 itself, or any of C4's Precedents.

Here is your code using the idea of Precedents:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Me.Range("C4"), Me.Range("C4").Precedents)) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Name = "Daily - " & Me.Range("C4")
    End If
End Sub
```